# no wicd-kde client on kubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

I'm currently running a Kubuntu 15.10 system which is really nice (beautiful and comfy, a bit slower than Ubuntu but no biggie).

My network-manager, though, flickers quite a lot..
It's not my first time with Kubuntu and I'd hope they'd fix that problem already but they didn't, so I searched a bit and found wicd-kde was a formidable substitute to the KDE native network-manager.

I installed wicd-kde following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD#For_KDE_.28Kubuntu.29) instruction page but didn't find the wicd client they mention on the "Configuring WICD" section.

The instruction page is not up-to-date but I'm not sure it's a compatibility problem with 15.10.

Has someone else faced this problem as well and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely situation is that you need to add the wicd widget into your taskbar. On the bottom right of your taskbar, there should be a symbol that allows you to access your taskbar options. In my KDE, it looks like this (to the right of the date):

[image: Look just to the right of the date]

Click it, then click "Add widgets...". You can then search for "Wicd", and select it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Debian wiki (but I think it's the same as Ubuntu):

1. You can install it through

   ```
   apt-get install wicd
   ```
2. Make sure you have added your regular user account to the netdev group

   ```
   # adduser yourusername netdev
   ```
3. Reload your DBus

   ```
   # /etc/init.d/dbus reload
   ```
4. Start the wicd daemon

   ```
   # /etc/init.d/wicd start
   ```
5. Start the wicd GUI with your regular user account

   ```
   # exit
   $ wicd-client -n
   ```
6. You can also start wicd to system tray icon by using

   ```
   $ wicd-client -t
   ```

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/761409) in Unity for wicd also.